# Linux Terminal Head Command Issue

Tags: linux, csv, ssh, terminal, command-line-interface

I am just starting to learn the basics of Linux terminal and I'm having some problems. I want to download a file using curl or wget and show its contents but when I type in the head command it gives me html scripts instead of the actual csv contents. Here's my code:

```
curl -O http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip
unzip ml-latest-small.zip
head -n 12 movies.csv
```

Here's what's returned:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://github.githubassets.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com">
  <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com">
```

But this is the output I want:

```
movieId,title,genres
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
6,Heat (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
7,Sabrina (1995),Comedy|Romance
8,Tom and Huck (1995),Adventure|Children
9,Sudden Death (1995),Action
10,GoldenEye (1995),Action|Adventure|Thriller
11,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Something is very off. If those are the actual commands you ran and they all succeeded, then the file you downloaded simply doens't contain what you expected. It's not at all clear why the CSV file extracted from the zip file wouldd contain HTML instead.

Comment: Also, this would probably be more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com, as this deals more with the usage of some command-line programs rather than scripting.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

well -- that's certainly strange - I just ran the exact command without error.

Did you CD into the newly unzipped folder you created?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ curl -O http://files.grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/ml-latest-small.zip

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  955k  100  955k    0     0   942k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  943k
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ unzip ml-latest-small.zip

Archive:  ml-latest-small.zip

   creating: ml-latest-small/
  inflating: ml-latest-small/links.csv  
  inflating: ml-latest-small/tags.csv  
  inflating: ml-latest-small/ratings.csv  
  inflating: ml-latest-small/README.txt  
  inflating: ml-latest-small/movies.csv  

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd ml-latest-small/

pi@raspberrypi:~/ml-latest-small $ ls

links.csv  movies.csv  ratings.csv  README.txt  tags.csv

pi@raspberrypi:~/ml-latest-small $ head -n 12 movies.csv

movieId,title,genres
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
5,Father of the Bride Part II (1995),Comedy
6,Heat (1995),Action|Crime|Thriller
7,Sabrina (1995),Comedy|Romance
8,Tom and Huck (1995),Adventure|Children
9,Sudden Death (1995),Action
10,GoldenEye (1995),Action|Adventure|Thriller
11,"American President, The (1995)",Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

Comment: Presumably not so obvious to the OP.

Comment: I didn't CD into the new file at first, but I just did and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome  :) Also - that's a really helpful command you've made! might be easier to just run head -n /ml-latest-small/12 movies.csv so you don't have to CD into it everytime